# ActiveMQ KahaDB compatibility

Tags: activemq-classic

We want to upgrade ActiveMQ 5.3 to 5.6 and also keep the connections information.
Here is what we do,

1. Backup files under `data\kahadb\` and uninstall AcitveMQ 5.3
2. Install ActiveMQ 5.6
3. Overwrite the files under `data\kahadb` with previous backup files

if the count of my clients is about 20, it works well.
if the count of my clients is more than 100, i can't connect to my broker again.
here are the logs in wrapper.log

```
Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml], reason: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.kahadb.page.Transaction$InvalidPageIOException: Page id is not valid
```

we got some exception when we created a consumer:

```
Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.BrokerException: java.io.EOFException : 
Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection.SyncRequest(Command command, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Session.CreateConsumer(IDestination destination, String selector, Boolean noLocal)
Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Session.CreateConsumer(IDestination destination)
```

Is the db compatible issue? or how to keep the connection data after upgrading MQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this thread : http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Migrate-existing-kahaDB-to-a-new-version-of-ActiveMQ-possible-td4486455.html, if overwriting the DB is not working, *you could simply create a Camel route that consumes msgs from the old broker instances and loads them onto the new broker. Some properties like timestamps or message ids will be changed however.*